# Unable to create pivot table, Key Error: 'Class'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

Error while creating pivot table

I am trying to create a pivot table from a Dataframe using Pandas. Given below is the view of my Dataframe

```
     Image                  Class           Score
0    cybage_ad_image2.jpg   palm tree       0.656
1    cybage_ad_image2.jpg   building        0.611
2    cybage_ad_image2.jpg   Christmas tree  0.730
3    cybage_ad_image3.jpg   person          0.746
4    cybage_ad_image3.jpg   person          0.633
```

Code to create Pivot table

```
df.pivot_table(index='Image',columns='Class',values='Score', aggfunc=sum)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-466-b38c8e51fd79> in <module>
      1 # df.set_index('Class')
----> 2 df.pivot_table(index='Image',columns='Class',values='Class', 
aggfunc=sum)
      3 # df.columns

c:\users\anirudhd\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot_table(self, values, index, columns, 
aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name)
   5301                            aggfunc=aggfunc, fill_value=fill_value,
   5302                            margins=margins, dropna=dropna,
-> 5303                            margins_name=margins_name)
   5304 
   5305     def stack(self, level=-1, dropna=True):

c:\users\anirudhd\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot_table(data, values, index, 
columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name)
     84     # group by the cartesian product of the grouper
     85     # if we have a categorical
---> 86     grouped = data.groupby(keys, observed=False)
     87     agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)
     88     if dropna and isinstance(agged, ABCDataFrame) and 
len(agged.columns):

c:\users\anirudhd\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _get_grouper(obj, key, axis, 
level, sort, observed, mutated, validate)
   3289                 in_axis, name, level, gpr = False, None, gpr, None
   3290             else:
-> 3291                 raise KeyError(gpr)
   3292         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
   3293             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: 'Class'
```

Could anyone guide me where am I going wrong with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know pandas (yet), but what I can see is that the examples for [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) use [`numpy.sum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy-sum), not the builtin [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), which is what I presume you are using as aggregation function.